# Can't Open Explorer in Sharepoint

Tags: explorer, ie8

I can't use "Open with Explorer" from SharePoint.

My setup:

```
      -SharePoint 2010
      -Internet Explorer 8
      -Windows 7 x32
      -Office 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Open in Explorer control was not visible

SharePoint 2010, Windows 7, IE 11, site already in compatibility view.

Adding site to Trusted sites list made the Open in Explorer control visible immediately.